I have created a react , I am unable to run this , earlier it was running fine but now getting error (Using parcel)
Earlier code was running fine , but suddenly it is giving error like,
enter image description here

ERROR
C:\Users\amitb\OneDrive\Desktop\React-Project>npm start
> react-project@1.0.0 start
> parcel index.html
Error: Got unexpected undefined
     at nullthrows (C:\Users\amitb\OneDrive\Desktop\React-Project\node_modules\nullthrows\nullthrows.js:7:15)
     at RequestGraph.invalidateOptionNodes (C:\Users\amitb\OneDrive\Desktop\React-Project\node_modules@parcel\core\lib\RequestTracker.js:248:44)
     at loadRequestGraph (C:\Users\amitb\OneDrive\Desktop\React-Project\node_modules@parcel\core\lib\RequestTracker.js:872:18)
     at async RequestTracker.init (C:\Users\amitb\OneDrive\Desktop\React-Project\node_modules@parcel\core\lib\RequestTracker.js:822:17)
     at async Parcel._init (C:\Users\amitb\OneDrive\Desktop\React-Project\node_modules@parcel\core\lib\Parcel.js:188:28)
     at async Parcel.watch (C:\Users\amitb\OneDrive\Desktop\React-Project\node_modules@parcel\core\lib\Parcel.js:260:7)
     at async run (C:\Users\amitb\OneDrive\Desktop\React-Project\node_modules\parcel\lib\cli.js:283:9) {
   framesToPop: 1
}

Package .json
{
  "name": "react-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "project1",
 
  "scripts": {
    "start": "parcel index.html",
    "build": "parcel build index.html",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "parcel": "^2.12.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.22.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "postcss": "^8.4.38",
    "process": "^0.11.10",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.3"
  }
}


This is my package.json
please help

Just delete the .parcel-cache file and do npm start .It should work.

It worked for me by deleting the .parcel-cache folder.
